# Print/Log full unstructured json from stream in Go

Tags: json, go

I inherited someone else's code for an API and since I'm not familiar with the requests that it's receiving I'm trying to print them or log them so I can see their structure. From what I've read about Go, jsons are decoded with Structs but since I don't know how the requests are received I cant write a struct.

I've tried the following on a basic API but they just print me out an empty map or nothing at all:

```
func createBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var result map[string]interface{}
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&result)
    fmt.Println(result)
```

```
func createBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    var book Book
    _ = json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&book)

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(r.Body)
    newStr := buf.String()

    reader := strings.NewReader(newStr)
    writter := os.Stdout

    dec := json.NewDecoder(reader)
    enc := json.NewEncoder(writter)

    for {
        var m map[string]interface{}
        if err := dec.Decode(&m); err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if err := enc.Encode(&m); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println(m)
    }

    book.ID = strconv.Itoa(rand.Intn(100000000)) // Mock ID - not safe
    books = append(books, book)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(book)
}
```

Is there any other way that it would print the received json without me knowing the strut beforehand?

Comment: It may be printing an empty map because your JSON input may be an empty object. Or it may be a simple value like a JSON number or string, or a JSON array, and arrays cannot be unmarshaled into a map. Or your input JSON may be invalid. Please do not ignore the returned error. Also, if you don't know if the input is an object or array, use `interface{}`, and the `encoding/json` package will select the appropriate type it can be unmarshaled into–`[]interface{}` in case of a JSON object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583735/unmarshaling-into-an-interface-and-then-performing-type-assertion

Comment: @icza I used interface on the first example but still returned an empty map, unless you mean something else. Also theres no returned error, I know that the json is valid as the code is able to process it just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use json.Unmarshal function

```
import "bytes"

 func createBook(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var result map[string]interface{}
     data :+ StreamToByte(r.Body)
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &result)
    if err !=nil{
        fmt.Println(err) //better to use log 
    }else
        fmt.Println(result)
   }
}
 func StreamToByte(stream io.Reader) []byte {
  buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
    buf.ReadFrom(stream)
    return buf.Bytes()
}
```

Refer : 
https://appdividend.com/2020/02/28/golang-how-to-convert-json-to-map-in-go/
https://gist.github.com/dixudx/3989284b142414e10352fde9def5c771

Comment: Thank you! The `StreamToByte` was exactly what i needed to be able to use unmarshal but I had no idea how to.