# Dynamic struct definition

Tags: json, go, struct

I have a use case where I'm converting some json fileto Go struct. I have the following document structure

```
{
    
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

    "paths" : [
      {
        "ParameterReference": "someValue",
      },
      {
        "ParameterReference": "someOtherValue",
      }
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "label": { "value": "label" },
        "domainName": { "value": "domain" },
        "servicePackageLink": { "value": "bin\\test.cspkg" },
        "pfxContent": { "value": "SampleCert.Content" },
        "sampleCertThumbprint": {"value": "SampleCert.Thumbprint"},
        "anotherSampleCertContent":{ "value" : "AnotherSampleCert.Content" },
        "anotherSampleCertThumbprint": {"value": "AnotherSampleCert.Thumbprint"}
    },
    "secrets" :[
      {
        "TargetReference":"SERviceConfiGURatiONLiNK",
        "Replacements":
        {
          "__Secret_Sample__" :
          {
            "SecretId":"secretID",
            "EncryptWith" :"encryptWithValue"
          },
          "__Another_Secret_Sample__" :
          {
            "SecretId":"anotherSecretValue",
            "EncryptWith" :"anotherEncryptWithValue"
          },
          "__Storage_ConnectionString__" : "someConnectionString"
        },
      },
      {
        "TargetReference":"None",
        "Certificates":[
          {
            "Name":"AnotherSampleCert",
            "ContentReference" : "contentReference"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

The issue I'm facing is that the json doesn't have a fixed schema, for eg.

1. If you check the `parameters` object, specifically the entries with names such as `sampleCertSchema`, in my use case, the user can provide any number of such *____CertSchemas* values raning from 0 to N. So, the parameter field can be the following too

```
"parameters": {
        "label": { "value": "label" },
        "domainName": { "value": "domain" },
        "servicePackageLink": { "value": "bin\\test.cspkg" },
        "pfxContent": { "value": "SampleCert.Content" }
    },
```

2. Another example is the `secrets.Replacements` object. The names of the individual replacement objects can be anything in the format of regex `/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/` and this is also a dynamic array as the `parameters` field mentioned in the first point. Therefore, another possible value for this can be

```
"Replacements":
        {
          "__Secret_Sample__" :
          {
            "SecretId":"secretID",
            "EncryptWith" :"encryptWithValue"
          },
          "__Storage_ConnectionString__" : "someConnectionString"
        },
```

3. With the field `paths`, I can be an array of objects or just an array of strings. Eg, other than the format above, it can also be

```
"paths": [
        "servicePackageLink",
        "serviceConfigurationLink"
    ]
```

With C#/Java I can create a document with the `Object` class to take care for these unknown dynamic object names and entries. With Go, I tried defining the following struct

```
type pathDefinition struct {
    ParameterReference     string `json:"parameterReference"`
    EnableHealthDimensions bool   `json:"enableHealthDimensions"`
}

type parameterValue struct {
    Values map[string]interface{}
}

type replacements struct {
    SecretValueMap map[string]interface{} `json:"secretValueMap"`
}

type resourceCertificate struct {
    Name              string `json:"name"`
    ContentReference  string `json:"contentReference"`
    PasswordReference string `json:"passwordReference"`
    Content           string `json:"content"`
    Password          string `json:"password"`
    Thumbprint        string `json:"thumbprint"`
    SubjectName       string `json:"subjectName"`
}

type resourceSecrets struct {
    TargetReference string              `json:"targetReference"`
    Replacements    replacements        `json:"replacements"`
    Certificates    resourceCertificate `json:"certificates"`
}

type ResouceParameters struct {
    Schema         string `json:"$schema"`
    ContentVersion string `json:"contentVersion"`
    Paths          interface{}
    Parameters     map[string]parameterValue `json:"parameters"`
    Secrets        resourceSecrets           `json:"secrets"`
    Others         map[string]interface{}    `json:"others"`
}
```

With this definition, I'm not able to unmarshal the file data into a `ResouceParameters` struct variable. Following is the way I'm unmarshalling

```
    file, _ := os.Open("path/to/parameters.json")
    defer file.Close()

    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(file)

    fileData := new(ResouceParameters)

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteValue), &fileData)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(fileData)
```

This prints an empty struct. My question is, how should I go about defining a struct in Go so that it is able to load a json with *non* predefined entries. With java/C# I could use the `Object` class and create a document, but I'm unable to understand to do this with Go.

Comment: You should be getting an unmarshaling error, because parameters will not be able to unmarshal to the struct you have. Use `map[string]interface{}` for parameters. Also, you don't need to `new`, simply declare the variable.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/x84GeEH__v9

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks for the example, it gives me an insight on what to do. I think you missed my edit to the question regarding `paths` field

Comment: @htyagi for paths do the same as with the `Secret`, implement the unmarshaler and based on the first byte decide how to unmarshal the individual element.

Comment: @mkopriva yeah, I tried doing the same, it is passing for this when paths is an array of objects, but fails when it is an array of strings https://play.golang.org/p/0dFb0bfL-6Z

Comment: @htyagi https://play.golang.org/p/SOsKGCZtlxk the name of the method matters, if it's `UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error)` it implements the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface, which causes it to be invoked automatically by the [`json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) function.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent in go is interface{}, the empty interface. For an example check out this answer: [Unmarshaling Into an Interface{} and Then Performing Type Assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583735/unmarshaling-into-an-interface-and-then-performing-type-assertion)

Once you know the term to search for you should be able to search up something more detailed if needed.

Answer (score 0):

@mkopriva Comments were something I was looking for.
https://play.golang.org/p/SOsKGCZtlxk